# How is the best way to integrate using loops

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, procedural-programming

I'm using Mathematica, and I want to integrate a function f[wr] in wr using some method that works with a Table/Do/For in the variable wr.

I tried to use something like the Riemann's sum, to evaluate the function in some point wr_0 times the spacing (in this case 0.01). The problem is that wr depends on "[Micro]" and for each value of Micro, the integral in wr would change its limits (from [Micro] - 50*kt to [Micro] + 50*kt).

```
kb = 8.61*10^-5;
Te = 300;
kt = kb*Te;
sum = 0;
sum1 = 0;
data = Table[
   {
    Table[
     {
      sum = sum + (f[wr]*0.01);
      sum1 = sum1 + (f[wr]*(wr - \[Micro])*0.01);

      }
     , {wr, \[Micro] - 50*kt, \[Micro] + 50*kt, 0.01}];

    \[Micro], sum1/(Te*sum)
    }

   , {\[Micro], -0.4, 0.4, 0.1}];
```

I think this code, is not doing what I want. That is, for each value of Micro, calculate the integral (sum1 and sum) for a range of wr's and store, then for other value of Micro, do it all again, at the end i want the output of the quotient of these integrals. How could I implement that?

To illustrate the idea. For each [Micro] I have one integral to evaluate. At the last [Micro] we need to sum all the other.

[image: tt [1]]

If you are interested in who is f[wr]: https://pastebin.com/7SwVvTen

Comment: You may define a helper function of `\[Micro]`: `data[\[Micro]_]:=Module[{sum=0,sum1=0},Do[sum = sum + (f[wr]*0.01); sum1 = sum1 + (f[wr]*(wr - \[Micro])*0.01);, {wr, \[Micro] - 50*kt, \[Micro] + 50*kt, 0.01}]; sum1/(Te*sum)]`. Then use it as a function itself `data[0.4]` or make a table `Table[data[\[Micro]],{\[Micro],-0.4,0.4,0.1}]`.

Comment: Doing like that, I get the same value of data[\[Micro]] for each \[Micro], i.e a horizontal line.

Comment: Try setting for `f` some function, e.g. `Sin` and see this plot: `ListLinePlot[Table[data[x] /. f -> Sin, {x, -0.4, 0.4, 0.1}],PlotRange -> All]`. It is far from a horizontal line.

Comment: I dont understand why I get the same value in the quotient for different values of \[Micro].

In[27]:= Table[data[\[Micro]], {\[Micro], -0.4, 0.4, 0.1}]

Out[27]= {{-0.4, 0.0042950}, {-0.3, 0.0042950}, {-0.2, 
  0.0042950}, {-0.1, 0.0042950}, {0., 0.0042950}, {0.1, 
  0.0042950}, {0.2, 0.0042950}, {0.3, 0.0042950}, {0.4, 0.0042950}}

Comment: Where I used: data[[Micro]_] := Module[ {kb = 8.61*10^-5, Te = 300, soma = 0, soma1 = 0}, Do[ soma = soma + (E^((wr - [Micro])/kbTe)/kb Te*((E^((wr - [Micro])/kbTe) + 1.)^2)*cond[wr]*0.01); soma1 = soma1 + (E^((wr - [Micro])/kbTe)/kb* Te*((E^((wr - [Micro])/kbTe) + 1.)^2) cond[wr]*(wr - [Micro])*0.01); , {wr, [Micro] - 50*kbTe, [Micro] + 50*kbTe, 0.01}]; {[Micro], N[soma1/(Te*soma)]} ]

Comment: In your last comment what is `cond[wr]`? And various `kbTe`, `kb Te` are confusing: is this a product, or one is in denominator but the other is multiplied? Please edit this simple `data[\[Micro]]` so one can copy/paste in MMA.To which `f` does your comment concern: to my simple `Sin` or your complicated one from pastebin?

Comment: Sorry about that. kb*Te is a product and are just constants, cond[wr] is the f[wr] given in the pastebin. 
`
data[[Micro]_] := Module[ {kb = 8.61*10^-5, Te = 300, soma = 0, soma1 = 0}, Do[ soma = soma + (E^((wr - [Micro])/kb*Te)/kb*Te*((E^((wr - [Micro])/kb*Te) + 1.)^2)*f[wr]*0.01); soma1 = soma1 + (E^((wr - [Micro])/kb*Te)/kb* Te*((E^((wr - [Micro])/kb*Te) + 1.)^2) f[wr]*(wr - [Micro])*0.01); , {wr, [Micro] - 50*kb*Te, [Micro] + 50*kb*Te, 0.01}]; {[Micro], N[soma1/(Te*soma)]} ]
`

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you need something like this:

```
data = Table[
  sum = sum + (f[wr]*0.01);
  sum1 = sum1 + (f[wr]*(wr - \[Micro])*0.01);
  {\[Micro], sum1/(Te*sum)},

  {\[Micro], -0.4, 0.4, 0.1}, {wr, \[Micro] - 50*kt, \[Micro] + 50*kt, 0.01}]
```

It calculates `sum`, `sum1` and adds the `{\[Micro], sum1/(Te*sum)}` into the resulting list at the each step in `\[Micro]`.

Comment: I got:

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of 2.97942*10^-22+sum.
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -3.84793*10^-22+sum1.
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -3.84793*10^-22+sum1.
General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: @LucasLopes, I don't have your `f[wr]` and due to this I tested this solution on the simple linear `f[wr_]:=2 wr`. It was working without any recursive loops.  Look at my code, do you see there any reasons for looping? It is trivial. So, problem is in `f[wr]`

Comment: f[wr] is obtained from an iterative method. The code is: https://pastebin.com/7SwVvTen

Comment: @LucasLopes, It works well on my PC with your `f[wr]`. The result is: https://pastebin.com/mTQW0AhE

Comment: Try now with the definition of f[wr]

Comment: Trying in this way: In[162]:= f[x_] := x^2;


Fun[y_] := Module[{sum = 0},
  
  Do[
   
   sum = sum + f[x]*0.001;
   
   , {x, y - 1, y + 1, 0.001}];
  
  N[sum]
  ]
Table[Fun[y], {y, -1, 1}]



Out[164]= {2.66867, 0.667667, 2.66867}


is equivalent to

f[x_] := x^2;
Table[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, y - 1, y + 1}], {y, -1, 1}]

Out[]={2.66667, 0.666667, 2.66667}